# Poner comillas simples para almacenar en mysql

Tags: php

Tengo que almacenar un array y que cada una de los datos tenga unas comillas simples y no tengo muy claro como hacerlo.

Estoy intentándolo así:

```
$Butacas = implode(",", addslashes ('.$_POST["Prot_asientos"].'.));
```

Pero me da error.

> ¿La sintaxis seria de esta manera?

este es el codigo completo sin el intento de comillas:

```
if (isset($_POST["Prot_asientos"])) { $Butacas = implode(",", $_POST["Prot_asientos"]); } else { $Butacas=""; } 

    $InuevoProt = Insertar_Datos("Protocolo" , "`idcontacto`, `confirmado`, `fechacontacto`, `plazas`, `asientos`, `entrega`, `aviso`, `fechaaviso`, `asistentes`, `evento`, `observaciones`", "
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $IdContacto)."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_POST['Prot_Confirmado'])."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $fecha)."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_POST['Prot_plazas'])."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $Butacas)."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_POST['Prot_entregadas'])."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_POST['Prot_recordar'])."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $fechaviso)."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_POST['Prot_asistentes'])."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_POST['Proyecto_Id'])."',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_POST['Prot_observaciones'])."'
    ");
```

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Ya lo he puesto.

Comment: Lo que estoy guardando es un string separado por comas, no se exactamente si me vale directamente desde mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Lo correcto seria:

- Agregar las comillas simples como parte del separador de `implode`.
- Agregar comillas simples antes y despues del `implode`.

#### Solución:

```
$Butacas = "'" . implode("','", $_POST["Prot_asientos"]) . "'";
```